# Node JS running but not responding. Works but then periodically stops responding

Tags: node.js, express, api-design

I've created my first ever NodeJS Api (first time JS too) and so am coming up against a few issues and was really hoping for some help/direction.

My current issue is that the API works however every now and then (more than once a day) it stops responding. (testing using postman). It doesnt respond with 'no response' it just keeps trying as if waiting for a response.

When I log into the node i use:

```
lsof -i tcp:3000
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    22361 [myserver] 18u  IPv6 190588033      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
kill -9 22361
```

When I kill it, i wait 10 seconds and it starts up again because i have installed FOREVER.

The issue is that it seems the node is there just... not functioning. If it crashed, wouldn't it restart and be working again but instead it is just "there".

How can I diagnose this?

I do also have Nodemon installed but can't really get it working properly as I get an EAINUSE error

- I have created the file on my VPS.
- SSH using Visual Stdio Code on my Win10 PC.
- Watched a few youtube vids to get me running
- My main js file is very basic:

js file:

```
const app = require('./app');
const port = process.env.port || 3000;
app.listen(port);
```

At the moment I can't seem to find "why" the node goes from working and responsive to stagnant, running but not actually working!

Happy to share code, just have about 12 js files and didn't want to throw too much on here.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "qudaapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "NodeJSAPI",
  "main": "qudaserver.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node qudaserver.js"
      },
  "author": "GAngel",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {   
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

App.js

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization");

    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE,GET');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});

//Import Routes
const chemistRoutes = require('./api/routes/chemists');
const smsHxRoutes = require('./api/routes/smsHx');
const authRoute = require('./api/routes/auth');
const webhookRoutes = require('./api/routes/stripehook');
const orderRoutes = require('./api/routes/orders');
const comboDataRoutes = require('./api/routes/comboData');
const staffRoutes = require('./api/routes/staff');
const orderListsRoutes = require('./api/routes/orderLists');
const contactLogRoutes = require('./api/routes/contactLog');
const licenseRoutes = require('./api/routes/license');

//Route Middleware
app.use('/smsHx',smsHxRoutes);
app.use('/chemists',chemistRoutes);
app.use('/register',authRoute);
app.use('/stripehook',webhookRoutes);
app.use('/orders',orderRoutes);
app.use('/comboData',comboDataRoutes);
app.use('/staff',staffRoutes);
app.use('/orderLists',orderListsRoutes);
app.use('/contactLog',contactLogRoutes);
app.use('/license',licenseRoutes);



app.use((req,res,next) => {
    const error = new Error('Endpoint not Found');
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
})

app.use((error,req,res,next) => {
res.status(error.status || 500);
res.json({
    error: {
        message: error.message
    }
    });

});


module.exports = app;
```

Section that is causing some kind of failed loop:

```
//Login_Get APIkey
router.post('/login',verifyQUDA,async (req,res) => {
    let loginChemist = req.body;
    const realPass = loginChemist.chemistPassword;
    
    // CHECK Password  
   
    var sqlString = "SELECT * From tblChemists WHERE userName = ?;";

        connection.query(sqlString,[loginChemist.userName], async (err,rows,fields)=>{
            if (rows && Array.isArray(rows) && rows.length) {

                    const savedHash = rows[0].chemistpass;
                    const chemistID = rows[0].chemistID;
                    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(realPass,savedHash);
                    

                    if(!validPass){
                        return res.status(200).json({
                            Result: false
                                })
                    }else{

                        const token = jwt.sign({_id: chemistID},process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
                        res.header('auth-token',token);
                        return res.status(200).json({
                            Result: true,
                            API_Token: token
                                })
                    } 

            }       
            })
        
        
        

})
```

So my code runs and I can use the API, I seem to be able to use it fine (all routes) and get the expected responses, however if I log in randomly and just do a test, sometimes it is down and POSTMAN just keeps spinning waiting for a response but when I check... it is still 'running'

Really keen to know what I should do to diagnose?

EDIT:
The code above is the section which sometimes loops or causes issues.
I have found that the api is in fact running as other API calls are working AND this API call "works" if I do not add the header.
Therefore I can get responses 500 if no header is there, or if the header API Key is incorrect.

The issue seems to be if the header is correct, and user and pass are correct sometimes I just get a looped response...
The code DOES work however and give the API_Token I need here and there but sometimes just loops like a nutcase!

Comment: You just have to log things in the server until you can narrow down where things are getting stuck.  For example, does an incoming request when it's stuck, get to the the very first middleware?  Or it doesn't even get that far?  Things I'd look for are: 1) Leaking database connections or database resources, 2) Leaking file handles, 3) Routes that don't have complete error handling and have some path where they fail to send any response when there's an error, 4) Some middleware that has a condition it can get into where it never calls `next()` or sends a response (thus hanging the request).

Comment: In the one route handler you show, it appears you're calling `res.status(200).json()` inside a loop with no exit after sending the response.  If you can ever get into this `if` statement more than once in your loop, this is wrong.  You get one response per request, not N responses.  That, by itself, probably wouldn't cause your symptoms, but is wrong and needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll look into those straight away and see what I can piece together

Comment: Are you running this in a production environment?

Comment: Currently it is just a test version with one user that uses it @AvivLo

Comment: @jfriend00  I have edited my question and added the code section that seems to be having some kind of loop issue... didn't know if you had any ideas on it.

Comment: That code you added has numerous code paths that do not return any response.  And, it's missing a bunch of error handling which would also cause no response to be sent.

Comment: @jfriend00 mmm yeh ok looking at it now I can see the big gaping holes.  If I encapsulate from the DB conenction section with a try catch, and also add an else to the rows/array length section that should be a decent start though, correct?

Comment: @GlennAngel - I proposed a more robust implementation in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/login` handler has numerous code paths that don't send any response and is missing some error handling, so you could end up with "silent" errors and hung requests.  Personally, I'd switch over to the promise API on your database, but without making that structural change, here's one way of at least making sure you always send a response and catch errors:

```
//Login_Get APIkey
router.post('/login', verifyQUDA, (req, res) => {
    const loginChemist = req.body;
    // CHECK Password
    var sqlString = "SELECT * From tblChemists WHERE userName = ?;";
    connection.query(sqlString, [loginChemist.userName], async (err, rows, fields) => {
        try {
            if (err) {
                // catch database errors
                console.log(err);
                res.sendStatus(500);
            } else if (rows && rows.length) {
                const savedHash = rows[0].chemistpass;
                const chemistID = rows[0].chemistID;
                const realPass = loginChemist.chemistPassword;
                const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(realPass, savedHash);
                if (!validPass) {
                    res.status(200).json({ Result: false });
                } else {
                    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: chemistID }, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
                    res.header('auth-token', token);
                    res.status(200).json({ Result: true, API_Token: token });
                }

            } else {
                // send some status here when the username does not exist
                // or your rows condition is not met
                res.sendStatus(404);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // this catches any exception in this scope or await rejection
            console.log(e);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much @jfriend00
I have used that code and it is running well.
I found that the (&& Array.isArray) section was not needed and I think that was causing issues too so I have removed it.
I will use that kind of design/handling for my other API pieces to clean them up. Thanks again for your time helping me

Comment: Ok so this has helped to narrow down the issue however it has still 'broken'
The API is working for all calls apart from this one, which has retruned the internal server error 500 response.  How can I figure what is wrong here considering the rest of the apis are working?

Comment: @GlennAngel - Well, everywhere the code I suggested sends an error 500 response, it also logs the details of the error, so I would suggest looking at that logging and see if you can figure out why it got there.  You can also add a lot more logging to examine everything and try to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @GlennAngel - There are three main ways this code generates a 500 error.  First, the database gave you an error.  Second, you threw an exception in your processing of the row data.  Third, the `await bcrypt.compare()` rejected.

Comment: ok thanks, so my last question (noob) is that If i go to my cmd screen and start the node, i can see the console as it prints, however if i close my cmd and the node Is running.. how do I access that log?

Comment: @GlennAngel - You can redirect stdout and stderr to files when you start your server so the logs are capture in a log file.  More advanced applications will use a logging tool beyond `console.log()` and directly log to files, implement log file rotation, log file aging, etc...

Comment: OMG I FOUND IT.  FOREVER uses logs and saves them into .forever.  This is literally what I have been needing for a month and now I can debug!!
THankyou so much.